# Vrai ou Faux? What is the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: sens

I'm doing a True or False exercise based on a short reading passage about mobile phones and texts. At one point the passage goes like this:

> Selon une autre enquête, le fait d'envoyer de nombreux sms est caractéristique de cette tranche d'âge. "Les pics se situent aux alentours de 16 ans et retombent généralemente vers 25 ans."

The questions is:

> Plus les etudiants vieillissent, moins ils envoient de textos

I say it's *Faux* because it's not the text messages, it's the pictures that peak around 16 years of age and fall around 25. Is it correct to assume so?

[[Link to full text]](http://www.french-tutor.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/GMS_B1.gif).

Comment: What pictures? *Les pics* is the peaks, not the pictures.

Comment: Gosh! Can you please click the link above and read the whole passage, please? Maybe there's more that I've misunderstood. Is it False then?

Comment: Read it, and I still don't know where you saw anything about pictures. Where do you see a reference to pictures? You might have misunderstood the word "pic" to mean "picture" — it means "peak".

Comment: I sure did. Still, is it correct to consider that statement *false*?

Comment: Qoba helped you to understand the [vocab](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/pic) that you had misunderstood but French Language is not meant to do your homework, FL is meant [to **discuss** the finer points of the French language](http://french.stackexchange.com/tour). I can see you aren't new to SE so please visit the Help Centre for FL.

Comment: Note that at least in France, *étudiant* has a narrower meaning that "student" in English. *Étudiant* is essentially used for university and similar level schools students but not primary (*écoliers*) and secondary schools (*collégiens* & *lycéens*).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the French Language as defined in the Help Centre. It should be reworded to fit French Language format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's clearly and directly asking for help with homeworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most French speaking countries, "étudiants" is quite restricted, and refers to persons in a higher education cursus, like post-baccalaureate ([Wikipedia source](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tudiant)):

> Dans la plupart des pays francophones, l'usage du mot étudiant est
>   encore plus restreint. Le plus couramment, il désigne les personnes
>   engagées dans un cursus d'enseignement supérieur.

In the initial text ("Selon une autre enquête..."), I see no mention of the word "étudiants", while "étudiants" is in the question. Generally, students are awarded a baccalaureate around 17-18 years. So if the peak is around 16, "étudiants" text above 17-18 text at a lower rate than at 16. If you assume that the rate is almost steady, perhaps slowly decreasing, and falls above 25, then the trend is globally decreasing from 17-18 to above ages.

In that context, the answer would be **true**.

However, one could imagine that people text a lot at 16, stop texting between 17 and 22, then suddenly re-text a lot between 23 and 24 (but at a slower rate than at 16, because it is the peak), and stop texting again after 25.

Then the answer would be **false**, because students at 23 text more than students at 20.

So from a purely logical point of view, I have not enough information to *true*, so I'd say *false*: there could be counter-examples.

But languages are not about pure logic, more about global statistical trends.  If something else in the text, or the global level of the test is about global understanding, without clever tricks to make you fail, I'd go for a "**true**", at the end. The text says "une autre enquête", which means that the first survey may carry additional information.

Answer (score 0):

it's true , "les pics" means in here the highest , "les pics " in franch has different meanning and it depends on the context , here are some meanings of "pics"

```
   les pics de pollution = pollution levels reach a peak
   les pics = Picinae (birds) 
   tomber à pic = coming in the right time
```

in here means the peak of sms use is between 16 and 25

Comment: Welcome to FL. Stack Exchange sites are not forums. Please visit the [help Centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)to see how to answer questions.  What you say is just a comment, to bea ble to answer questions you will have to acquire a little more [reputation](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: hello i'm new in here , i'm going to edit my answer so that i can better explain .

Comment: Howdy! It's quite common for newcomers to use some code blocks in their content instead of blockquotes; you can have line breaks and other formatting within blockquotes etc. ([link](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)) Thanks.